# Why are there no Sentinel-2 images in northern latitudes from November to January?

Tags: sentinel-2, imagery, satellite, esa

I have found that there are no Sentinel-2 images in northern latitudes from November through January (near 64.11837149, 67.75836280 coordinates).

[image]

Number of scenes around the point with coordinates 64.11837149, 67.75836280 (you can see that from December to January there is no scenes here).

[image]

Number of scenes wordwide (you can see that from October to April their number decreases).

I found a link to the [Sentinel-2 Acquisition Plans Archive](https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/missions/sentinel-2/acquisition-plans). It says we won't be getting any high-latitude scenes during the winter months, but it doesn't explain why.

Here's a screenshot of the scheduled shooting from December 16 to January 3.

[image]

**I can't find an explanation for this on the official website. What is the reason for the lack of scenes?**

Comment: This isn't really a GIS question, and might be better asked on the Earth Science stack site?

Comment: This is just a guess: The quality gets bad with long shadows. How are you producing those graphs?

Comment: @Spacedman Disagree. Quote: "Geographic Information Systems is a question and answer site for people interested in GIS, **Remote Sensing**, Photogrammetry, Geodesy and Surveying, as well as Programming/Databases specific to the aforementioned."

Comment: @BERA The graphs were created on the website https://geohazards-tep.eu/. The absence of images for this site is also confirmed on the site https://scihub.copernicus.eu/ (i.e., it is not a problem of the third-party site).

Comment: I would guess this has to do with short daylight and poor conditions. At 64N, the sun rises around 8 and sets around 16 at 1st Nov, but at noon, the height is just approx 11 degrees.  I cannot see from your graph at exactly which date it stops, at that latitude the daylight changes quickly at that time of the year, on NOv 15, sun rises at approx 8:45, sets at approx 15:15 and has a max height of 7 degrees.

Comment: @ComradeChe From the ES stack info pages: "You are also welcome to ask questions about techniques or data sources related to these [Earth Science] disciplines.". These two sites are so overlapping... take to meta or chat if you want to discuss.

Comment: Absolutely disagree with this close reason, this question completely on-topic here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Sentinel-2 mission uses a [sun-synchronous orbit](https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/missions/sentinel-2/satellite-description/orbit) and was planned to produce image products with similar **local constant viewing conditions**. The planned **Local Time at Descending Node** per image is **10:30 AM** (means local acquisition time of the scene).

The [local sun location data (sunrise, solar noon and sunset)](https://gml.noaa.gov/grad/solcalc/sunrise.html) for your provided location at the 2020-11-15 and 2021-01-30 are:

```
 - sunrise:     09:28 AM
 - solar noon:  12:00:59
 - sunset:      02:34 PM
```

And from the 2020-12-11 to 2020-12-31 there is "no local solar noon" present at your provided location:

```
 last sunset:      12:34 PM 11 December 
 next sunrise:     12:32 AM 31 December
```

**NOAA sun inclination and daylight tool:**

[image]

So the sun inclination is IMO to low or simply not present, to get proper reflection for the samples of the [2A product](https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/product-types) (Bottom-of-atmosphere reflectance in cartographic geometry).

In addition the **local constant viewing condition constraint** limits the acquisition/ correction of image products *from neighboring overlapping tracks* (means locally overlapping but different sun inclination angles) and is problematic due to the fast changing of the sun inclination angle in this period.

These condition constraint starts to diverge in the winter season at higher latitudes and the summer season at lower latitudes and is sketched at [Sentinel-2 MSI User Guide -- Revisit and Coverage](https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/revisit-coverage).